# How can i get the keys of an object stored in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Lets just prefix this for the moderators this question is not about nested Key's. This is about an array in an object and how to see if its a simple array with only values or if it is an array which holds objects and how to get the keys of these objects. I included code snipped which parses the sample and detects the 2 Array's. What i am looking for is to return only name of array if the array is simple array with only a list of values. If the array is array of objects i would like to get the keys of that object in array.

```js
obj = {
            DocId: "email_campaign::3ed76589-4063-49f6-a21e-9ca16981d102",
            history: {
                created_by: "",
                created_on: "",
                update_on: "",
                updated_by: ""
            },
            librarys :[{id: 1, name : 'Lib 1'},{ id: 2, name: 'Lib 2'}],
            status: "Active",
            subject: "Test 1 Subject",
            summary: "",
            tags: ['one', 'two'],
            template_id: ""
        };

const keyify = (obj, prefix = '') => 
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, el) => {
    if( Array.isArray(obj[el]) ) {
      // Here needs to go the Array Part
      console.log(el + ' is Array')
      return [...res, el];
    } else if( typeof obj[el] === 'object' && obj[el] !== null ) {
      return [...res, ...keyify(obj[el], prefix + el + '.')];
    } else {
      return [...res, el];
    }
  }, []);
  
  
const output = keyify(obj);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output structure for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the names of arrays prefixed similarly to the existing prefix for objects, you could try this:

```
const keyify = (obj, prefix = "") =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, el) => {
    const elDisplayName = `${prefix}${el}`;
    if (Array.isArray(obj[el])) {
      const objectsInArray = obj[el].filter(el => typeof el === "object");
      if (objectsInArray.length > 0) {
        let objectKeys = [];
        objectsInArray.map(object => {
          objectKeys = objectKeys.concat(keyify(object, prefix + el + "."))
        });
        return [...res, ...new Set(objectKeys)];   
      }
      return [...res, elDisplayName];
    } else if (typeof obj[el] === "object" && obj[el] !== null) {
      return [...res, ...keyify(obj[el], prefix + el + ".")];
    } else {
      return [...res, elDisplayName];
    }
  }, []);
```

There are many caveats to this solution, like assuming if an array has a single object, it will contain only objects. But this should give you a start on detecting the presence of objects in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on an array to check every item against a case.

To check for an array you can use `Array.isArray()`.
To check for an object you can use `typeof variable === 'object'` however, arrays are also classed as object types so you will need to check it is also not an array with the above method.

Example using your use case

```js
const isObject = (arrayItem) => {
  if (typeof arrayItem === 'object' && !Array.isArray(arrayItem) && arrayItem !== null) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

const array1 = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2]
];
const array2 = [{
  key: 'value'
}, {
  key2: 'value'
}];

console.log('array1', array1.every(isObject)); // false
console.log('array2', array2.every(isObject)); // true
```

Comment: To test if something is an array you should use `Array.isArray()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: Ok so now i can check if the array is simple and has objects but how can i get the keys of the object in array ?

Comment: @MisterniceGuy `Object.keys()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: To test if something is an object you need to exclude `null`, because in JavaScript `typeof` says that `null` is an object.